# Checkboxes in listview are reset onPause of android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

**What i have:** Listview with checkboxes hosted in activity

**What is happening:**

1. onPause happens and the screen restores the checkboxes are re-setted
   to their original state
2. How to resolve this

---

## In activity

```
AdptHomeDetail serialNumbers = new AdptHomeDetail(ActMyOrderDetail.this, result.getMyOrderDetails().getSerialNumbers());
lstVwId.setAdapter(serialNumbers);
```

### In Adapter

***AdptHomeDetail.java***

```
public class AdptHomeDetail extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<SerialNumbers> mSerialNumbers;

    private Context mContext = null;

    public AdptHomeDetail(Context context, ArrayList<SerialNumbers> serialNo) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mSerialNumbers = serialNo;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mSerialNumbers.size();
    }

    public SerialNumbers getItem(int position) {
        return mSerialNumbers.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        final ViewHolder vHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layout.inflate(R.layout.adp_act_myorder_detail, null);
            vHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(vHolder);

            vHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    mSerialNumbers.get(getPosition).setIsChecked(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                }
            });

            view.setTag(R.id.checkBox, vHolder.checkBox);

        } else {
            vHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        vHolder.checkBox.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        vHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mSerialNumbers.get(position).isChecked()); // Restore the maintained checkbox state

        vHolder.txtNameId.setText(mSerialNumbers.get(position).getProduct().getName()) ;
        vHolder.txtSlnoId.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.myOrderDetailSlnoTag) + " " + mSerialNumbers.get(position).getSerial_num() + "") ;

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        private TextView txtNameId,txtSlnoId;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public ViewHolder(View base) {


     txtNameId = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.txtNameId);
        txtSlnoId = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.txtSlnoId);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) base.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> onPause happens and the screen restores the checkboxes are re-setted
>   to their original state

This is normal behaviour. No one answer above won't work (work properly). What you have to do is to use **onSaveInstanceState()** where **you will store your selections** in ListView or whatever AdapterView you are using and then in onCreate() "regenerate" your selections.

So in Adapter you can save your check states into *SparseBooleanArray* where you will store position of checkbox and checked/unchecked state.

In *onSaveInstanceState()* method you will store them.

In *onCreate()* method you will regenerate it such:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // init widgets

   // after activity was re-created during rotation
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      // restore your selections in Adapter
   }
}
```

This should solve your problem you are facing.

**Update:**

> are there any samples that show how to use sparce boolean arry

Basically you just need to create for example onCheckedChangeListener and attach it into your checkbox in each row in your AdapterView. In this listener you will use current position of item and checked/unchecked state:

```
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      mSparseArray.put(position, isChecked); 
   }
});
```

where position you can obtain in your **getView()** method directly and **isChecked** state is current state of checkbox as method param.

Comment: Thanks ! [+1] ... are there any samples that show how to use sparce boolean arry for this use case in stackoverflow or other place

Answer (score 0):

either you can create a class which extends class "Application" and save the state of check boxes there, so that onResume of your activity you can restore the state of your check boxes

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `onResume()` method.